# How do I convert an ACF field from a string to an integer?

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

[image]The client will be entering information for the year a report was produced (eg. 2010). I want to take that information and calculate if it was made in the last 3 years so I can display it in a 'recent documents' section. Any other report that doesn't match the result will be sent to an archives section. Am I thinking through this correctly?

```
<?php if( have_rows('recent_documents') ): ?>

                <ul class="list-unstyled">
                        <?php while( have_rows('recent_documents') ): the_row(); ?>
                            <?php if ( have_rows('new_document') ): ?>
                                <?php while ( have_rows('new_document') ): the_row(); ?>
                                    <?php $year = the_sub_field('year'); ?>
                                    <?php if ( $year > date("Y",strtotime("-1 year"))) : ?>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="<?php the_sub_field('file'); ?>" target="blank"><?php the_sub_field('year'); ?> <?php the_sub_field('report_type'); ?><span><i class="fas fa-download"></i></span></a>
                                        </li>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                <?php endwhile; ?>
                        <?php endif; endwhile; ?>
                </ul>

            <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing to fix is `the_sub_field('year')`, as it will print out your year string instead of passing it to your variable.  Instead, I think you want

```
$year = get_sub_field('year');
```

And, to answer your question, it's easy to convert a string to an int by passing `(int)` in front of the item.

```
$year = (int)get_sub_field('year');
```

Answer (score 1):

Advanced Custom Fields (ACF) support forums…
You can filter a field "type" to cast to and then return a specific data type.

```
    function strict_type_acf_numeric_field($value, $post_id, $field): int
{
    $value = (int) $value;
    return $value;
}

add_filter('acf/format_value/type=range', '926i_strict_type_acf_numeric_field', 10, 3);
add_filter('acf/format_value/type=number', '926i_strict_type_acf_numeric_field', 10, 3);
```

[reference link](https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/trying-to-check-for-number/)